# Why did remove() method of the python list give me unexpected results?

Tags: python, list

I learning Python, and I come across this:

```
x = [1,0]
x.insert(0,2)
x.remove(x[-1])
print(x)
```

and the result is `[2, 1]` which is expected.

But then I change a value to insert to be 0.

```
x = [1,0]
x.insert(0,0)
x.remove(x[-1])
print(x)
```

and the result is `[1, 0]` which is unexpected. I expect the result to be `[0, 1]`.

What did I miss here?

Comment: `remove` will remove the first occurrence of the element. See `help(x.remove)` for more info.

Comment: Try `del x[-1]` instead of `x.remove(x[-1])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.remove` removes the *first* item equal to the argument. `x[-1]` evaluates to 0, so it removes the first 0, which is the first element of your list. Just because you used `-1` to index `x` before calling `list.remove` doesn't necessarily mean it will remove the element at index `-1`.

See `list.remove`'s documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

You can call `list.pop`, which takes the *index* of the element to remove instead of the element itself. In your example, replacing `x.remove(x[-1])` with `x.pop()` (defaulting to last index) will yield expected result.

Answer (score 1):

`list.remove` removes the first item its finds that matches the parameter passed. If you want to just remove the last element you can use `pop()` without parameters or `pop(-1)`.

From docs:

> list.remove(x) Remove the first item from the list whose value is
> equal to x. It raises a ValueError if there is no such item.
>
> list.pop([i]) Remove the item at the given position in the list, and
> return it. If no index is specified, a.pop() removes and returns the
> last item in the list. (The square brackets around the i in the method
> signature denote that the parameter is optional, not that you should
> type square brackets at that position. You will see this notation
> frequently in the Python Library Reference.)